# Python OpenCv Homography

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am new to opencv and after an extensive search I have not found any detailed explanation to how one can implement a homograph. For example if I wanted to say... have a side shot of a chess board or a book and wanted to make a new image look as if the original were shot head on. I would try providing some code to show I attempted a solution but outside of knowing some of the functions I would need I am not sure how to implement them to solve my problem.

I am using python 2.7
thank you,

Comment: This is too broad of a question for the Stack Overflow site, as linking to off-site resources is off-topic and links can die off with websites. With that said, the tutorial at https://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/ is very popular, so start there.

Comment: Also I've answered a few questions about that specific blogpost on Stack Overflow, so you can [browse through my answers which include the term homography](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5087436+homography) if you get stuck on something and see if any of those answers helps you out.